# What's the figure of speech used in "Get the facts, or the facts will get you. And when you get them, get them right, or they will get you wrong."?

Tags: figures-of-speech

Is it [epanalepsis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epanalepsis) or [antimetabole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antimetabole)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Antanaclasis. Review the examples shown here:

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antanaclasis

Answer (score 0):

It's part Antanaclasis, but that is nested within an overarching [chiasmus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chiasmus) structure.
a,b,b,a, usually in an antithetical pairing.
An example is found in Leapor's '[An Essay on Woman](https://www.poetrynook.com/poem/essay-woman)':

> Despised, if ugly; if she's fair, betrayed.